# Running out of memory when using pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using pyplot to plot and save a series of figures in a loop. Each iteration of the loop produces and saves 14 figures. I use garbage collection, and close the figure after each iteration. The first few iterations of the loop run with no problem, but it eventually spits out an "out of memory" error. SInce a single iteration runs ok, and garbage collection is used, I am inclined to think that there should be no problems in running the loop any number of times. Why does this code produce an "Out of Memory" error after a few iterations?
This is what the code looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import gc as gc

.
.
.

for i in MyDays:

   fig = [0]

   fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))

   ax[0] = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
   ax[0].bar(index,histogram1[i],alpha=opacity,color='darkblue')

   ax[1] = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
   ax[1].bar(index,histogram2[i],alpha=opacity,color='darkblue')
   .
   .
   .
   fig.savefig(PathToDirectory + " Day "+str(i+1)+".png", dpi=800)
   plt.clf()
   plt.close()
   gc.collect()
```

Comment: The `gc` only cares about reference cycles, regular objects will be collected as soon as there are no more references to them. If there still are, `gc` won't collect them either. (unless you are using pypy, which doesn't run matplotlib). How do you *read* data? We've had a buggy input library (ROOT) cause memory leaks when plotting.

Comment: I read data from a CSV file and process it and put it into a dataframe. I am positive that it's the above loop that leads to the memory leak, but I cant figure out why. Is there anyway I can completely delete all figures and re-generate them with every loop?